# Can i set my local gitlab runner to wait when other pepline in different repo is running?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to make my local runner pending all new pepline when other pepline in different repo is running

Comment: I think you need this? https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/multi_project_pipelines.html

Comment: Can you explain the scenario you have? Are you triggering this pipeline and waiting for it? Why do you need to wait for it? etc.

Comment: I have small instance and the pepline looks like consume too much memory, and sometimes i got problem when building docker (storage limit), so i need to set only one pepline running and others waiting

Answer (score 0):

You can't setup a global lock like this, but there may be a way to get what you need to avoid over-using your runner resources.

> I have small instance and the pepline looks like consume too much memory [...] so i need to set only one pepline running and others waiting

You can set the concurrency limit for your runner with the `concurrent` setting in the configuration TOML file. Then your runner will only run the specified number of job at a time. With the docker executor you can also set per-job memory limits with the `memory` configuration.

For example, you might want to set the limits such that `concurrent * memory = your instance available memory` that way your jobs cannot attempt to use more memory than is available. If you want only 1 job to run at a time, set `concurrent` to `1`.